# How to Trigger an email in the Event that a Logic App Trigger is skipped?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have the below scenario:
I have a Logic App, which gets triggered once in every day(24hours).
It basically looks at a SFTP location, if there is file dropped in there, pulls it and pushes it into a BLOB storage and then deletes it from the source(SFTP).

I need to trigger an email in the events of:

1. If the Trigger is "Skipped", i.e. it ran but could not find any file in the SFTP.
2. If it failed to Upload to the BLOB Storage.

Is it possible to enable Email Trigger in the above scenarios?(1&2)
Any guidance will be appreciated as I am new in the IAC space.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can List the files in FTP and pass the name to get the content of the files using `List files in folder` and `Get file content` actions of `SFTP` connector.

> 1. If the Trigger is "Skipped", i.e. it ran but could not find any file in the SFTP.

For this, in the next step you can use a condition action to check if the file has been uploaded for that day by comparing the last modified time with the current date. If yes, then create a file in the blob storage with the file contents from `Get file content` step. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

> 2. If it failed to Upload to the BLOB Storage.

For this you can create another condition action and check if the file is been created or not by using `actions('Create_blob_(V2)')['outputs']['statusCode']`. Below is the complete code of my Logic app

[image]